# Is there any exception notification gem for ruby project?

Tags: ruby, exception, rubygems

I am developing a ruby project, not rails project. Is there any exception notification gem for this case? thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Exceptions happen just fine in plain Ruby.  What type of notification do you want?

Comment: is looking for railsless analogue of https://github.com/rails/exception_notification.

Comment: right! if there is exception, i need one mail

Comment: Ruby toolbox category: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/exception_notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest solution depends from wich method did you like to send mails.

If you have for example already installed sendmail - in this case to send the mail with notification log you can call it with params. It depend on your system settings.

Comment: Question asked for a gem to send error notifications. Spawning a sendmail process is not a gem. Furthermore it is a brittle solution.

Answer (score 3):

Although quite young, the following is an intentionally non-Rails exception notification gem: https://github.com/Moove-it/rusen

Comment: +1 as "rusen" is still maintained three years later, is very simple, and still appears to be one of very few solutions not Rails-specific.